# python playwright expect pytest class

Tags: python, pytest, playwright, expect

How to check expectation if a class contains a word and want to check if a tenant has that word in the class

example of a class:
"x-grid-row x-grid-data-row x-grid-row-selected x-grid-row-focused".

the point is to make this expect check if the class contains
"x-grid-row-selected"

Regards
Paulina S.

How the assertion check should look like with expect

Comment: https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-class ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is a "tenant"? I've never heard of this concept in the context of HTML/CSS/Playwright. `expect(page.locator("x-grid-row-selected")).to_be_attached()`? `expect(some_other_locator).to_have_class("x-grid-row-selected")`? There are many possible solutions, and without more context, it's unclear which might help in your case.

Comment: And also it is unclear who Paulina is.

Comment: thanks, I'll check it tomorrow because I have to improve the test and I'll finish my work for today. it looks promising

Comment: and when it comes to tenant, it was some kind of translation error because the question was whether the class contained this expression in its name